# Markov clustering algorithm in Java

Tags: java, graph, cluster-analysis

Is there any open-source [Markov clustering algorithm](http://www.micans.org/mcl/) (aka MCL) implementation in Java? Either standalone or part of a library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is this [implementation](http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/api/0.1.1/net/sf/javaml/clustering/mcl/MarkovClustering.html) included into the [java-ml](http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/) libary.

Comment: This library is currently at version 0.15. I would suggest caution.

Comment: I tested the library; it rely on a poorly-designed sparse matrix implementation, and the performance is really bad, even for medium data size. I'm currently writing it myself, based on a specially designed sparse matrix implementation (using Trove).